# Submit not working on my Pligg 2 site

Tags: submit, pligg

after researching this issue I removed all widgets and all modules and tried to create a new post, however it still didn't submit. The only posts that are showing are the ones I made about 2 weeks ago.

Then I thought it was a server side issue. So I have checked my disk space which is good, it appears mySQL is working ok as I deleted 18 discarded posts from it via the Pligg Admin panel. And my webhost has worked fine with Pligg so far so I imagine that it is compatible.

Does anyone have any ideas of how I can resolve this issue please? The site is: www.yuity.com. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I also faced this issue sometime for some URL, pligg show error if the URL has space in between
There is way to solve it if you like, you put validate URL to false in setting panel